# Blender's "Automatic weight" and weight is 0, it will be blank

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I did Blender's "Automatic weight".
I set two bones in a simple cylinder and did Automatic weight.
The weight has been set successfully.
However, the vertex of weight 0 is not zero. It is blank.

Brushes 0weight with the brush tool, and its vertex is input 0 for weight value.
But, If more the number of vertices..

Can I automatically enter 0 for weight value instead of blank for weight 0?

Please tell me how if someone know.

[image]
(Both images activate Bone1)